# Throwing error after deployment of asp.net project

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-deployment

I am using webforms, it works fine on local machine but the time when i deployed the project server on it throws me the following error. I am not getting where it is coming from.

i am using following packages in the project:

1. Captcha.3.0.16.0
2. jQuery.2.1.3
3. jQuery.UI.Combined.1.11.4

Here is the error screen which i am getting:

Error Description:

```
Server Error in '/CabeePortal' Application.
Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Reference.svcmap: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error:


[No relevant source lines]


Source File: /CabeePortal/App_WebReferences/CabPortalWS/    Line: 1

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' could not be loaded.


WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929
```

[image]

Comment: Did you deploy System.Web.Mvc?

Comment: You should put the error information in the question itself, rather than using an image. Or the image can be supplementary. But it's better for search engines and copy/paste reasons if you have the error information as actual text.

Comment: @demonplus it is not an mvc project....it consists of webforms.

Comment: @mason...good point...i will do it right away...thanks...

Comment: Why does it need System.Web.Mvc? Do you have it in references?

Comment: Make sure your using the correct version of .net, sure you dont wanna be using MVC 3, or even 4?

Comment: @demonplus well i read the documentation of "Captcha.3.0.16.0" and it consisted of some mvc thing but it said that it support webforms also, then i removed its folder and code as well but still it threw the same exception.

Comment: @thatuxguy...i am using webform not MVC

Comment: You are using MVC 2.0 somewhere and you need either deploy it or remove reference.

Comment: @demonplus i searched the key word mvc in the entire solution but it did not existed.